# How to run detox for react-native projects on windows and linux?

Tags: linux, windows-10, react-native, detox

I am currently using windows 10. I want to be able to run detox test scripts on android emulators. Is this possible?
I tried to do it many times but failed. Each time I do it, some configuration issue pops up and build gets failed.
The CI/CD server is hosted on a Linux machine, so assuming we can do this, will it run there?
Also is there any good guide available to help in setting up and running detox for react-native projects on windows?